# How to Prohibit a Particular Option of a Dropdown to Send Value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In Rails 5.1 I have a dropdown created with time_select helper from a table column of "time" data type:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <%= form_for(Sleep.new) do |f| %>
   <%= f.time_select :hours, {minute_step: 5, prompt: true, order: [:hour]} %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

The prompt sets the dropdown to "Hours" string by default. In html, this line doesn't have any value:

```
<select id="sleep_hours_4i" name="sleep[hours(4i)]">
<option value="">Hour</option>
<option value="00">00</option>
```

However, when a user doesn't choose anything from the dropdown and submits it with the default "Hours" option, the form sends the value to the db:

```
0001-01-01 00:00:00
```

Since the value of "Hours" isn't nil, my validation (which should give user a notice if nothing was selected from the dropdown) doesn't work.

How can I still have "Hours" default but set this option's value to nil (prohibit sending any values to the db on submission of this option) and be able to give user a notice like "Choose an hour!" in this case?

Comment: Do you need to have a prompt? If not you can just turn it off and that way you don't have this problem.

Comment: You can also validate against a blank value, that's another possibility. Something like `validates :hour, presence: true, allow_blank: false`

Comment: Removing prompt just makes some random hour from the list a default.

Comment: Random hour? When I try this it always selects the first, `00`

Comment: value="" means that I shouldn't get a value when <option value="">Hour</option> is submitted, correct? Currently whatever I set as a default, I'm getting some value to the db, both with prompt or without it, hence no validation. Maybe I could say "If get the value equal to 0001-01-01 00:00:00, give user a notice to pick an option", but I can't figure out how to do this as well. I tried validates :hour, presence: true, allow_blank: false, doesn't seem to change anything. Sorry If I'm not getting something that might be obvious, just new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that all you needed to have a default prompt that sends null to db if no option is selected and sends value to db if an option is selected is to add `ignore_date: true` to `f.time_select` attributes. So I just turned

```
<%= f.time_select :hours, {minute_step: 5, prompt: true, order: [:hour]} %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.time_select :hours, {minute_step: 5, prompt: true, ignore_date: true, order: [:hour]} %>
```